# Unable to get a EJB business object

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-2.x

I have a situation where I need to call methodB() of an EJB from methodA() of the same EJB, with a new transaction starting in methodB().

I read on some threads that getting a reference to the EJB through

```
sessionContext.getBusinessObject(EjbLocalInterface.class);
```

will work. But it gives me a

> java.lang.Exception: com.ibm.ejs.container.UnknownLocalException:
>   nested exception is: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Requested
>   business interface not found.

I am currently working on EJB 2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[javax.ejb.SessionContext.getBusinessObject()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/SessionContext.html#getBusinessObject(java.lang.Class)) is an EJB 3.0 method.

I've used [javax.ejb.SessionContext.getEJBLocalObject()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/SessionContext.html#getEJBLocalObject()) to do what you're trying to do successfully in the (distant) past. You will need to cast it to your business interface though.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to get a proxy to the EJB local object interface through this method.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to manually start and close the transactions if you use bean managed transactions:-

[Bean Transaction Types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/undejdev008.htm#CHDIIJDE)